# URL Masking!With Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, dns, subdomain, masking

I'm quite new here so i have a problem about masking and tried other solutions using .htaccess as well but no luck, that's why im here. Thanks.

Ok here's it is:

1. I want my http://www.domain.com/article-tip to show in http://www.subdomain.domain.com
2. It means the page content is from: domain.com/article-tip
3. But the url above the address is:  subdomain.domain.com
4. How would i do that using .htaccess?

It means i also tried the iframe and frames and php, but i want the .htaccess

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: You need to utilize the **ReverseProxy** functionality (in addition to URL Rewriting) of Apache.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mod_rewrite` in that case the URL will be `subdomain.domain.com/article-tip` but in php URL will be `www.domain.com/article-tip`.
I don't think you can send dynamic output to browser like what you want with `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you need to get all files in article-tip to point to the subdomain. The subdomain should also point to the subdirectory. This is for the .htaccess of the subdirectory.

```
RewriteRule ^article-tip(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^article-tip/(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```